# Failed to delete the virtual machine extension in Azure ARM VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I am getting a error message while removing the extension from a Linux VM in Azure Resource Manager Mode .

Failed to delete the virtual machine extension 'CustomScriptForLinux'. Error: VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'VMAccessForLinux'. Error message: "Enable failed.".

Answer (score 1):

Removing some VM Extensions is not supported; others have properties that can be set that change VM behavior radically.
You can remove the extension by using Azure PowerShell cmdlets or by using the Service Management REST API operations.

Remove-AzureVMExtension – Use the cmdlet to remove classic VM extension

Remove-AzureRmVMExtension – Use the cmdlet to remove ARM VM extension

For more details on removing the extension check the link [Add, Update, or Disable Extensions.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/features-windows?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Fclassic%2Ftoc.json)